# Remote Restart RDP Server using Batch Script

Tags: remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop, rdp

I have 10 RDPs running Windows Server 2019, which I need to restart every once in a while manually. For the same, I need to log in to each server and restart them.

I wanted to have a batch script created which can restart all servers in one go. All RDP servers are on the public internet IP ( and not on local LAN ), and are protected by a complex password.

I tried searching for various solutions over the web and in this forum but didn't find any.

TIA.

Comment: Remember that vpn is a better solution if you're talking about security.

Comment: If your firewall lets you send remote commands, you can send remote command to shut down server and reboot them. shutdown /m \\RemoteServerName /r /c “Comments”

Comment: You can also use task scheduler to program when to reboot every server by its own.